# pydeck r.show() outputs TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute

Tags: python, deck.gl

Until now, everything worked just fine. I've created a new file to create new heatmap. My dataframe is looks like this:

```
time                     name      lng     lat
2019-10-16 08:00:00       A      23.1113   34.123123
2019-10-16 09:00:00       B      12.1113   11.123123
2019-10-16 07:30:00       C      134.1113   12.123123
2019-10-16 08:40:00       D      122.1113   12.123123
2019-10-16 08:50:00       A      16.1113   12.123123
```

which is always exact same as dataframe I've used before when creating heatmap exact name, and other columns.

copy paste previous code for creating heatmap:

```
layer = pdk.Layer(
    "HeatmapLayer",
    df,
    get_position="[lng, lat]"
) 
center = [126.986, 37.565] 
view_state = pdk.ViewState( 
    longitude=center[0], 
    latitude=center[1],
    zoom=10
)
r = pdk.Deck(layers=[layer],
             initial_view_state=view_state,
             mapbox_key=MAPBOX_API_KEY)
r.show()
```

When I run w/o r.show() it doesn't show anything, when I run with r.show() it outputs `TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute`

I cannot figure out what is wrong...

Comment: I can't replicate this bug–can you verify that it still exists?

Comment: @duber still exist...

Comment: Ghirardi Nicola's solution fixes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens to me and the solution was passing to pydeck only the needed column.
In your case df[["lng", "lat"]]
It could be an issue linked with any N/A values in any columns of the pandas dataframe but i'm not sure.

Comment: Please provide more explanation if possible.

Comment: Yes, this fixes it Thanks! but want to know why this is happenning to some df but not other df.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is a bit old. But for the people that may be facing this issue with newer versions of pydeck, in my case it was because the arguments:

```py
latitude=center_lat, longitude=center_lng
```

of the `pdk.ViewState` function were not floats but `np.float32` variables. A simple cast such as `float(center_lat)` worked.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue while trying to plot a H3HexagonLayer. Since none of the provided solutions worked for me it follows what solved my problem.

I just substituted the original data frame df by:

```py
df = pd.read_json(df.to_json())
```

A bonus is that I didn't need to constraint the columns to the ones that are being explicitly used. Moreover, deck.show() and deck.to_html() also worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it using `r.to_html()` instead of `r.show()`

Comment: hm... Sometimes it works but sometimes this does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, and I suspect `pydeck` is not happy with one of your df columns, probably `time`. Did you create the data in this column using numpy? In my case, a simple np function:

`color  = np.random.choice(range(256), size=3)`

was raising the same issue. The way I solved it was to add `.tolist()`, so it will be converted to a normal list/array. After that, passing it to pydeck was working well as the `color` prop.

My suggestion is to go back to where you create this column, and try to "simplify" it for pydeck. Ghirardi answer is also correct, but will force you to drop data that might used in some way during the rendering (i.e color by `time` etc)

Answer (score 0):

I was sending np arrays

```
grouped_df.apply(lambda x: list(x[[LON, LAT]].values))
```

Which were messing with the json conversion. they needed to be lists:

```
grouped_df.apply(lambda x: list(x[[LON, LAT]].values.tolist()))
```